# Data and salt arguments required

Tags: node.js, mongoose, bcrypt

I'm trying to hash the password of admin in my site. I have searched and found out that this error is because of being `null` or `undefined` the value that we want to hash it.

here is my code, whenever I console.log(admin) it returns `{}`, I don't know why.

```
adminSchema.pre('save', (next) => {
    var admin = this;
    console.log(admin)
    bcrypt.hash(admin.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
        if (err) return next(err);
        admin.password = hash;
        next();
    });
});

var adminModel = mongoose.model('Admin', adminSchema);
module.exports = adminModel;
```

server side code:

```
var adminModel = require('./../models/admins');
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    var newAdmin = {
        adminName: req.body.adminName,
        faculty: req.body.faculty,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    }

    adminModel.create(newAdmin, (err, admin) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('[Admin Registration]: ' + err);
        }
        else {
            console.log('[Admin Registration]: Done');
            req.session.adminId = admin._id;
            res.redirect('/admin/submitScore')
        }
    })
});
```

Unfortunately, I can't find the reason of that the console.log(admin) is empty. I would be thankful if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword `this` changes scope when used in arrow functions. [See more here](https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4). This is not a problem in your express route, but in your mongoose middleware it is. Change your function to not use `this` or make an old fashioned `function(){}`